# Multiple Sequential Async JavaScript Functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, race-condition

Let's say I have a function that looks like this:

```
var foo = function(callback) {
  var final = {};

  asyncFuncOne(function(x) {
    final.x = x;
  });

  asyncFuncTwo(function(y) {
    final.y = y;
  });

  callback(final);
});
```

Obviously, this doesn't do what I want it to do (call `callback` on `final` when it has both x and y). I have several questions:

1. Is there a way to do what I want it to do without nesting everything?
2. Does the current form introduce a race condition? Are both async functions accessing the same `final`?

Comment: Both asynchronous functions do access the same `final`.  However, their results will *not* be passed to the `callback` function, so `final.x` and `final.y` are essentially lost.

Comment: You either nest the callbacks, or use promises, otherwise there's no way to know that the async functions has completed.

Comment: @adeneo, is there a simple way to use promises here, without rewriting asyncFuncOne/asyncFuncTwo?

Comment: That depends on wether or not they already return a promise, otherwise you have to actually write code that either returns a promise from the functions, or resolves an already created promise in the callbacks etc.

Answer (score 2):

**Approach #0. Painful life without promises. Yet life**

Actually, your code like cries to be rewritten in promises. Trust me, this refactoring is something you 100% need. But ok, let's try to solve this particular problem without invoking promises at all - just as an exercise. Actually before the promise era the pattern was to introduce a special function that checks whether we can consider that we are done or not.

In your particular case such function is:

```
function weAreDone() {
   return final.hasOwnPropery('x') && final.hasOwnProperty('y')
}
```

Then we can introduce asyncFuncDecorator:

```
function asyncFuncDecorator = function(asyncFunc, asyncFuncHandler) {
   return function(doneFunc, doneHandler) {
       asyncFunc(asyncFuncHandler);
       if (doneFunc()) {
          doneHandler();
       }
   }
}
```

With this two functions introduced you can write something like:

```
var foo = function(callback) {
  var final = {};

  //here goes abovementioned declarations
  ... 

  asyncFuncDecorator(asyncFuncOne, function(x) {
    final.x = x;
  })(weAreDone, callback);

  asyncFuncDecorator(asyncFuncTwo, function(y) {
    final.y = y;
  })(weAreDone, callback);

});
```

You can keep working on making this approach more flexible and universal but, once again, trust me, 
you'll end up with something very similar to promises, so better promises ;)

**Approach #1. Promisifying existing functions**

If, for some reason, you are not ready to rewrite all you functions from callback style to promises,
you can promisify existing functions by using, once again, a decorator. Here's how it can be done for native Promises, which are present in all modern browsers already (for alternatives, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises)):

```
function promisify(asyncCall){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
         asyncCall(resolve,reject);
    });
}
```

In that case you can rewrite you code in this fashion:

```
var foo = function(callback) {

      //here goes abovementioned declarations
      ... 

      Promise.all([promisify(asyncFuncOne), promisify(asyncFuncTwo)]).then(function(data) {
          // by the way, I'd rather not to call any variable "final" ))
          final.x = data[0];
          final.y = data[1];
      }).then(callback);

    });
```

Not to say that actually foo it's better to be promisified itself ;)

**Approach #2. Promises everywhere. From the very beginning**

It worth to reiterate this thought - as soon as you need to trigger some function after N other async functions should be completed - promises in 99% cases are unbeatable. It almost always worth trying to rewrite existing code to in promise-based style. Here's how can such code look like

```
Promise.all([asyncFuncOne(), asyncFuncTwo()]).then(function(data) {

  return Promise.resolve({
    x: data[0],
    y: data[1] 
  })

}).then(callback);
```

See how much better it become. Also, a common mistake of using promises - is to have a sequential waterfall of thens - retrieving first chunk of data, only after that - the second one, after that - the third one. You actually never should do this unless you are transforming data received in Nth request depending on what you've got in one of your previous requests - instead just use *all* method.

This is very crucial to understand. This is one of main reasons why promises quite often are misunderstood as something excessively complicated.

Sidenote: as of December'14, native Promises are  natively supported by all major modern browsers except IE, and in Node.js has native promise support is a thing since version 0.11.13, so in real-life you still most probably will need to use promise library. There's a lot of Promise spec implementations, you can check [this page](https://promisesaplus.com/implementations) for the list of standalone promise libraries, it's quite big, the most popular solutiona are, I guess, Q and bluebird.

**Approach #3. Generators. Our bright future. Well, may be**

This is something worth to mention, generators are de-facto supported in Firefox, Chromium-based browsers and node.js (called with  --harmony_generators option). So, de-facto, there are cases when generators can be used, and actually are already used, in production code. It's just that if you are writing a general-purpose web app, you should be aware of this approach but you'll probably won't use it for a while. So, you can use the fact that generators in js allow you to invoke two-way communication through yield/iterator.next(). In that case.

```
function async(gen) {
    var it = gen();
    var state = it.next();

    var next = function() {
        if (state.done) {
            return state.value;
        };  
        state.value(function(res) {
            state = it.next(res);   
            next();
        }); 
    }   

    next();
}

async(function* () {
    var res = { 
        x: yield asyncFuncOne,
        y: yield asyncFuncTwo
    }   

    callback(res);
});
```

Actually, there are already dozens of libraries which do this generator wrapping job for you.
You can read more about this approach and related libraries [here](http://gajus.com/blog/2/the-definitive-guide-to-the-javascript-generators).

Comment: I disagree that Promises, or even the refactor in approach #0 is necessary -- or even better -- for this simple problem. But I am +1'ing for the Promise.all usage. You should also mention that Promises are not natively supported in all browsers, modern or otherwise.

Comment: @rgthree, native Promises are supported in literally all modern browsers except IE, added this to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I know that IE lacks, however "except IE" is exactly the meaning not all modern browsers (especially one with the majority of the marketshare). Further, they are also not natively supported on Android KitKat or iOS 7.1 and previous (both of which have more marketshare than their newer versions). In fact, _40% of all browser users across the globe **are not**_ using a browser that natively supports Promises. I think it would have been foolish to not mention that (or recommend an lib as you have added) in a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

`final.x` and `final.y` are set on final, but *after* it's sent to `callback` so, unless the callback is waiting, `x` and `y` are undefined when callback receives them.

You could check to see if one has come back in the response of the others and call out to the callback:

```
var foo = function(callback) {
  var final = {};

  asyncFuncOne(function(x) {
      final.x = x;
      if (typeof final.y !== 'undefined') {
          callback(final);
      }
  });

  asyncFuncTwo(function(y) {
      final.y = y;
      if (typeof final.x !== 'undefined') {
          callback(final);
      }
  });
});
```

You could nest your callbacks, though this will cause `asyncfuncTwo` to not be called until `asyncfuncOne` has finished):

```
var foo = function(callback) {
  var final = {};

  asyncFuncOne(function(x) {
      final.x = x;
      asyncFuncTwo(function(y) {
        final.y = y;
        callback(final);
      });
  });
});
```

Then there are Promises. These are the future of async however they are not fully supported across all browsers (namely, all of IE [11 and below at the this time]). In fact, **40% of all browser users are not using a browser that natively supports Promises**. This means you will have to use a polyfill library to give you support adding substantial filesize to your page. For this simple problem and at this given time I wouldn't recommend using Promises for this simple issue. However, you should definitely read up on how they are used.

If you want to see what that could look like, it'd be this:

```
var asyncFuncOne = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // A 500 seconds async op and resolve x as 5
        setTimeout(function() { resolve(5); }, 500);
    });
};
var asyncFuncTwo = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // A 750ms async op and resolve y as 10
        setTimeout(function() { resolve(10); }, 750);
    });
};
var foo = function() {
    var final = {};
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        Promise.all([
            asyncFuncOne(),
            asyncFuncTwo()
        ]).then(function(values) {
            final.x = values[0];
            final.y = values[1];
            resolve(final);
        });
    });
};

foo().then(function(final) {
    // After foo()'s Promise has resolved (750ms)
    console.log(final.x + ', ' + final.y); 
});
```

Note no callbacks, just use of `then`. In a real scenario you would also use `catch` and `reject`. Read more about Promises here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise but, again, I personally don't see a strong need to use them for this single, specific issue (but, to each their own).

Comment: you don't need to call asyncFuncOne and asyncFuncTwo sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to create a setter:

```
var foo = function (callback) {
    var final = {
        setter: function(attr,value){
            this[attr] = value;
            if (this.hasOwnProperty("x") && this.hasOwnProperty("y"))
                callback(this);
        }
    };

    asyncFuncOne(function(x) {
        final.setter("x", x);
    });

    asyncFuncTwo(function(y) {
        final.setter("y", y);
    });
};
```

Answer (score -2):

One pretty bad idea, but I've had to use it before, because I wasn't about to import a 50k promise library for a single function, would be to set a looping Timeout that checks to see if all the required variables are set, and then calls the callback.

Comment: That really would be a bad idea, as the functions clearly have callbacks that can be used instead.

Comment: Of course, having callback functions that can be used doesn't help you in the slightest bit for this function, since you need both of the callbacks to have succeeded before you can continue.  Which in Javascript that doesn't have promises, isn't something that you can do without doing it this way, or explicitly setting checks in both callbacks to see if the other callback has completed first.  .. and personally, I'd consider having one callback depend on another callback completing is just as bad an idea, if not worse.